# Using variable name as object key in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is this possible?

```
    static readonly statusMapping: { [key in UploadStatus]: PopupMessageStatus } = {
        UploadStatus.COMPLETED : PopupMessageStatus.COMPLETED
    }
```

`UploadStatus` is just an enum (numeric values) - `UploadStatus.COMPLETED = 0`

maybe something like:

```
    static readonly statusMapping: { [key in UploadStatus]: PopupMessageStatus } = {
        [UploadStatus.COMPLETED]: PopupMessageStatus.COMPLETED
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are just missing square brackets:

```
static readonly statusMapping: { [key in UploadStatus]: PopupMessageStatus } = {
    [UploadStatus.COMPLETED] : PopupMessageStatus.COMPLETED
}
```